# How to handle donation in multiple Forms?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my site there are 4 steps of donation. Every steps has some information. like
1 page:(Perk, credit card info)
2 page:(name, card no, expiry date, etc)
3 page:(other shipping address related information)

how can i maintain these steps??

one user can donate multiple times in one project.

Comment: AJAX is the best way, otherwise you might be able to hold some info within session variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use session to store each page information.   At last page store all
   information into database
2. Use ajax